Milvus Services Failing to Start Due to Missing Permissions in public/default Namespace
I am encountering issues starting the Milvus services (rootcoord, datacoord, querycoord, indexcoord). The services continuously restart with errors indicating that permissions for the public/default namespace are denied. Below are the details:
Logs:
time="2024-12-12T10:34:10Z" level=error msg="[Failed to create producer]" 
error="server error: ServiceNotReady: Namespace bundle for topic (persistent://public/default/cpic-milvus-rootcoord-dml_0) 
not served by this instance:broker:8080. Please redo the lookup. Request is denied: namespace=public/default" 
topic="persistent://public/default/cpic-milvus-rootcoord-dml_0"

Steps Taken:

Executed the deployment command:
docker stack deploy -c milvus-coord.yaml milvus --with-registry-auth


Assigned the following roles (admin, others, rootcoord, querycoord, indexcoord, datacoord) the permissions:
[produce, consume, functions, sources, sinks, packages].

Despite these changes, the services fail to start, and the error persists.
What additional roles or permissions need to be configured for the public/default namespace to allow these services to start successfully?
